# AWS S3 Console Download Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm noticing some files that were uploaded into s3 cannot be downloaded via console. When I select the file and click download button, it eventually fails. Is there a way to debug the issue? The download does not provide an error message other than failed.

[image]

Comment: When you say "eventually fails", are these particularly large files? Do they download quickly, and then slow down? Can you try from another browser or another network connection (eg office vs home vs tethered via your phone)? Network issues are typically the cause of such behaviour.

Comment: This was true across three colleagues as well. Files were ~ 80 MB. They seem to start downloading and then goes to failed status. Oddly enough, we're able to download the files today. Since we're all in different states, I can only assume it was on the AWS side?